# How to add/remove view buttons on Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I have `Project Explorer` view open on my `Debug` perspective with this buttons circled in black:

[image]

How can I edit them? I noticed I can edit perspective, but not views. Is this possible?

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible. The first three buttons are only displayed if _Go Into_ has been used. The three last circled buttons are shown for all views: view menu, minimize view stack and maximize view. The fourth last button (three circles) is from Mylyn and only shown if Mylyn is installed.

Comment: @howlger, concerning about Mylyn, uninstalling all of it from Help -> About Eclipse IDE -> Installation Details e restarting did the trick. The first three buttons disappeared after restarting, even using 'go into'. Hum, if you want to state an answer, please. If not, I'm going to post as an answer a mix of our comments. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Feel free to give a self-answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to `Help` -> `About Eclipse IDE` -> `Installation Details` tab `Installed Software` and shift selected all `Mylyn` related software. After uninstalling it and restarting, the three circles grey icon was gone.

The three dark grey icons are default to all views: view menu, minimize and maximize and thus cannot be altered.

The three first arrow buttons was gone at Mylyn restart. Kudos to @howlger